# Is it possible to set the default volume per application?

Tags: applications, settings, audio

Some of the apps I use have very different output levels. One is only comfortable with volume set to the minimal and another is inaudible at that level, so I am constantly raising and lower volume between apps. Just like there is a separate ringer and media volume.
Is it possible to have some level set at a different level in every application? Some would have a default level until specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be too cliché if I said “There’s an app for that.”? Here’s the link:

[App Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spycorp.appvolumecontrol)

Comment: Good. Works exactly as described.